# insert row into datatable with textbox in rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I am trying to implement insert two text box with same row in datatable  same row  of searching box I am trying by following way

custom.js

```
$(window).load(function (){  
var table = document.getElementById("example");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
 });
```

but i cant to do that...plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just do `$("#example").append("<tr><td>" + "NEW CELL1" + "</td></tr>");`

Comment: but if you can .plz tell me add text box into datatable..beside datatable search box.with same div